# How can I save my text formatted in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following `save` method to store a blog post at **MongoDB**, but I want to save my text formatted the way the user writes it, with tabs and different paragraphs, this way it just saves all text at once, no formatting allowed, how can I do it?

```
app.post("/postNovo", function(req,resp){
    var post = new postsModel({
        titulo: req.body.titulo,
        texto: req.body.texto``
    });

    post.save(function (err, obj) {
        if (err){
            resp.render("resposta", {login: req.session.logado, mensagem: "Ocorreu um erro no cadastro, atualize a página e tente novamente"});
        } else {
            resp.render("resposta", {login: req.session.logado, mensagem: "Cadastrado com Sucesso!"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You will need to retain the formatting information in the string that you are saving, by somehow capturing the hidden formatting characters in your front-end client before sending to the server.

Comment: *" ... it just saves all text at once, no formatting allowed*". That's not correct. MongoDB is actually storing the data **exactly** how you sent it, within the constraints of UTF-8 encoding unless you deliberately do something else. That means all line breaks and tabs and other things are certainly stored, "as long as you actually sent them that way".

Comment: So you are either not actually storing things how you think, and you have something else altering the data. Or the most commonly obvious is that the display mechanism ( like HTML, which you seem to be doing ) does not actually care about things line "linebreaks" and "tabs" and actually expects valid HTML to maintain formatting. Unless of course you put everything inside a `<pre></pre>` that is. Check that you don't have a method scrubbing input before you store it, and then make sure you a looking for that retention in a "valid" form of output.